# Setting payloads for invoking Lambda Functions

Tags: java, collections, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a Lambda function from another Lambda function in Java. I am following the code provided in this Question ["How to call an aws java lambda function from another AWS Java Lambda function when both are in same account, same region"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483042/how-to-call-an-aws-java-lambda-function-from-another-aws-java-lambda-function-wh).

Refer to this statement in the code:

> invokeRequest.setPayload(ipInput);

Where I am guessing the `ipInput` variable is a String.

What I need to know is how should I set a payload, that is not String? In my case, the Lambda function accepts a `List<Double>` input. From what I read, it seems I need to convert it to a JSON String. I am sceptical about how? Is there a difference between the JSON representation of `Double[]` and `List<Double>`? Also, is there any helper method in AWS SDK (or the Collections API), which can do that cleanly?

Comment: Can't the lambda function be changed to accept String and typecast string to Double as a part of execution?. Just a thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-from-java/) on the AWS Devloper blog regarding this topic.

You could implement a proxy.

Otherwise you could check the AWS SDK directly on [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-lambda/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.java) or go to the official [java-doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/model/InvokeRequest.html#withPayload-java.lang.String-)
there seem to be two options for your payload either you pass a `ByteBuffer` or a `String`. It seems like you cannot pass a `Double` or a `Double[]` directly. You have to wrap those in a JSON-String. I'm receiving JSON messages containing numbers and it works quite well. Try something like:

```
String myDoubles = "{\"doubles\": [1487851012.924, 1487851012.925]}"
invokeRequest.setPayload(myDoubles);
```

Comment: The `myDoubles` example didn't work for me, but the proxy example did.