# Invoke a a lambda function from a lambda function written in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is there any good documentation how to invoke a lambda function from a lambda function written in java? 
Is there a difference between invoking a lambda function from a lambda function or invoke from a normal java application?

The only thing that I found is the normal AWS Java SDK doc.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

Would be happy if someone could help me.

Comment: lambdas are shorthand for functional interfaces, if you have an instance of one you'd call it like a normal method. If you're talking about something else, then post your actual problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call lambdas normally from lambdas, just as you would if your code was executing on a host somewhere.

You'll have an additional step of ensuring that the lambda executing the call to another lambda has permissions to execute other lambda functions (the permission is called ["lambda:InvokeFunction"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)).

The rest of the steps are the same as regular java using the AWS SDK, you instantiate an [AWSLambdaClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html) object, set your credentials and settings (region, etc.) and then create an `InvokeRequest` object which is the sub-lambda to be called with the appropriate payload.

[Here's some sample java code which does exactly this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36483042/808532), but it's also part of the standard sdk docs.

And also keep in mind that you'll still be subject to the original timeout for the first lambda, otherwise execution will be stopped.

Here's the relevant code snippets that you should be able to work from, I've made a change to how the second lamdba is called in terms of credentials - your can pass the credentials used to invoke the first lambda implicitly into the second one, which is probably a bit easier and more maintainable - you just need to ensure that the first lambda call gets the credentials and the rest will inherit them.

```
    Region region;
    AWSLambdaClient lambdaClient;

    lambdaClient = new AWSLambdaClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
    region = Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(regionName));
    lambdaClient.setRegion(region);

    InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest();
    invokeRequest.setFunctionName(FunctionName);
    invokeRequest.setPayload(ipInput);


    returnDetails = byteBufferToString(
            lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest).getPayload(),
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"),logger);
```

edit: I should also point out that depending on your architecture, there's probably much cleaner options like using SQS, or depending on how simple your nested lambdas are, inlining them directly inside each other to avoid the extra call.

Comment: Make sure you pass `InvocationType='Event'` to ensure child invocations are asynchronous

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack - It probably depends on his use case, but I assumed he wanted to call another lambda function and then get the result back to do further processing in his first one, which means he should leave the default lambda Invocation Type call as `RequestResponse` so that it's *synchronous* - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax

Comment: Ah true. I'd assumed that if the OP wanted to call more synchronous code, then they would put it within the same Lambda method. I guess we don't know :)

Comment: Actually I just want to pass data to the second lambda function, so I think asynchronous would be the right way to do it. Thanks for everyones help so far!

Comment: "And also keep in mind that you'll still be subject to the original timeout for the first lambda, otherwise execution will be stopped" I don't think there is any dependency between the child lambda and the parent. The child will continue running happily after the parent has completed (provided of course you kick off the child async AND give time for the invocation to start before the parent completes). I think you were probably talking only about a sync invocation, but just wanted to make it clear you can make a completely independent child lambda.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the used API functions are deprecated and the AWS docu is ... I share a new implemented example. The Lambda function "updateS3Chart" calls another Lambda function "AsyncUpdate" asynchronous:

```
public class LambdaInvoker {
static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LambdaInvoker.class);
static final String LambdaFunctionName = "AsyncUpdate"; 

private class AsyncLambdaHandler implements AsyncHandler<InvokeRequest, InvokeResult>
{
    public void onSuccess(InvokeRequest req, InvokeResult res) {
        logger.debug("\nLambda function returned:");
        ByteBuffer response_payload = res.getPayload();
        logger.debug(new String(response_payload.array()));
    }
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void updateS3Chart(UpdateS3ChartRequest updateS3ChartRequest) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
        //issue: aws region is not set to debug-time. solution for eclipse:
        //environment variable is set by lambda container or eclipse ide environment variables
        //use instead for eclipse debugging: project -> Run as -> Run Configurations -> Environment -> Add variable: "AWS_REGION": "eu-central-1"
        AWSLambdaAsync lambda = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.defaultClient(); //Default async client using the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain and DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain chain
        InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest()
            .withFunctionName(LambdaFunctionName)
            .withPayload(gson.toJson(updateS3ChartRequest));

        Future<InvokeResult> future_res = lambda.invokeAsync(req, new AsyncLambdaHandler());

        logger.debug("Waiting for async callback");
        while (!future_res.isDone() && !future_res.isCancelled()) {
            // perform some other tasks...
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.debug("Thread.sleep() was interrupted!");
            }
            System.out.print(".");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.fatal("Execute async lambda function: " + LambdaFunctionName + " failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

You have to set your AWS region as system property in your IDE for debugging (see comment in source code for Eclipse). UpdateS3ChartRequest is simple POJO with property set/get.